# How to create Test (JUnit) "Sign In" for Firebase?

Tags: java, android, firebase, junit, firebase-authentication

How write correct Test "Sign In" for Firebase ?

```
public class LoginActivityTest {

    private FirebaseAuth mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    private static final String email = "test@gmail.com";
    private static final String password = "qwerty46";

    @Test
    public void singInTest() throws Exception {
        mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email,password).addOnCompleteListener((Executor) this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                Assert.assertEquals(true, task.isSuccessful());
            }
        });
    }
}
```

This test has error

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.<clinit>(SourceFile:131)
    at com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth.getInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.sanke46.android.e_commerce.ui.navigation.LoginActivityTest.<init>(LoginActivityTest.java:18)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:217)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:266)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:263)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMainV2.main(AppMainV2.java:131)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Method getMainLooper in android.os.Looper not mocked. See http://g.co/androidstudio/not-mocked for details.
    at android.os.Looper.getMainLooper(Looper.java)
```

Comment: It looks like you're trying to create a unit test in place of an API or integration test.

Comment: @user1055395 Yes you are right, but I don't know do I correct or not ?

Comment: Why not to create an Espresso test here? It will be simple. It doesn't make sense to write a unit test for FirebaseAuth because you should test your code and not that of FirebaseAuth.

Comment: @user1055395 you are right :-) I can do this

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JUnit testing on class with firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43225349/junit-testing-on-class-with-firebase)